# Does .net nuke support ajax?

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetnuke

When i try to add a .ascx control which uses ajax, I get an error.

Is there any way to include ajax built controls in .net nuke?

Answer (score 1):

ever since the year of 2007 ;-)
http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Blogs/tabid/825/EntryId/1410/DotNetNuke-4-5-and-ASP-NET-AJAX.aspx